# Not able to Login after connect Android client with local XMPP server

Tags: android

```
  I am using asmack library for connect local XMPP server.
  it connects properly with local server but it gives me problem 
  while login ..

 {
   SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);
    ConnectionConfiguration cc = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.11",5222,"360degree");
    /*cc.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    cc.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);*/
    connection = new XMPPConnection(cc);

    try{
        connection.connect();
        Log.d("TAG1", "m in try1111111");
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAN",0);

        connection.login("kutbi1@360degree","kutbi1");
        Log.d("TAG1", "m in try12121212121212");
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
        presence.setStatus("Gone fishing");
        Log.d("TAG2", "m in try2222");
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
      }

    Same code is work for Facebook chat connection with XMPP.
```

Answer (score 0):

SASL is basically a standard for using secure authentication. Client currently uses SASL authentication between Openfire and Smack, so it should work for you. The first thing to determine is whether or not your server supports this feature, so what server are you trying to use? If your server does not support SASL, you can tell Smack not to use it through the setSASLAuthenticationEnabled method in the ConnectionConfiguration class.